# Where does SSH pull autocompletion from?

Tags: bash, ssh, autocomplete

I am on an enterprise network in which double tabbing after ssh leads to it spitting out suggestions of computers to ssh to. However, what I've noticed is that depending on which computer I am on, a different set of computers will be suggested. Removing `.ssh/known_hosts` doesn't change the behavior. Where is ssh pulling in these suggested computers?

Comment: It's not SSH. What shell are you using? `bash` and `zsh` have quite different ssh completion scripts.

Comment: the shell is bash

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The OpenSSH is using bash completion from package `bash-completion`. The responsible script is stored in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ssh` (on Fedora. Might be different on different distros). The `_known_hosts_real` function is defined globally in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` and you can see it is using all of the below (known hosts is only one of the sources):

- Known hosts:

  - User known hosts file `~/.ssh/known_hosts`
  - Global known hosts file `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`, `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2`, `/etc/known_hosts`, `/etc/known_hosts2` ...
- Configuration files (Using `host` aliases mostly, but also `Hostname`s)

  - User configuration file `~/.ssh/config`, `~/.ssh2/config`
  - Global configuration file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`
  - The configuration file provided using the `-F` switch
  - Included configuration files
- In cluster public keys `~/.ssh2/key_22_<hostname>.pub` (I don't know why)
- hosts reported by `avahi-browse`
- hosts reported by `ruptime`
- results of normal hostname completion

For details about specific source of information, you should consult the source code.

Comment: How on earth do I parse known_hosts to remove one specific host?

Comment: @KlaymenDK The known_hosts has the first field of hostname or IP address. Just find that line and remove it. If it is hashed for whatever reason, use `ssh-keygen -R hostname`. It is there for this particular use case.